# Can multiple websites/domains be hosted by the same Platform as a Service [PAAS]?

Tags: wordpress, apache, tomcat, hosting, paas

Sorry if this is trivial, but I am still learning the basics of PAAS, so I appreciate your patience...

1. **Can separate websites both be hosted by a single PAAS (used via single account with a given popular PAAS-provider)?**

I think they can, but I'm not certain, and want to make sure...

In particular, I want to host both a Wordpress blog (whose PHP needs Apache) & a Java WAR webApp (with servlets needing Tomcat); each served for different domains.  So these would be independent websites.

2. *I think if yes to 1., hosting separate sites with 1 PAAS is possible, and Tomcat & Apache are both in its stack, then I can host the particulars I mentioned with the single PAAS?*

I was initially planning to do all of this with a traditional web hosting provider, but have realized I can probably achieve the same with a PAAS for cheaper & simpler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself with OpenShift that the answer is **Yes** to both questions 1. & 2.  I hosted a Wordpress and a .war on separate domains on the same OpenShift account (each on a separate Wordpress gear).